# How can a node in an execution plan have smaller costs than its child?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan, cost-based-optimizer

I always thought that a node in an execution plan can only be executed after its children have executed, and thus the total cost of a node has to be greater or equal than the cost of the child nodes. However, this is not always the case, like in the following example:

```
Plan hash value: 2810258729

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                              |    10 |  1170 |  3871   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                           |                              |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                                   |                              |    10 |  1170 |  3871   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|   3 |    VIEW                                  | V_TOP_GENRE                  |    10 |  1170 |  3871   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|   4 |     WINDOW SORT                          |                              |    10 |   890 |  3871   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|   5 |      MERGE JOIN                          |                              |    10 |   890 |  3871   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|   6 |       VIEW                               |                              |   345 | 10350 |  3867   (1)| 00:00:47 |
|   7 |        SORT GROUP BY                     |                              |   345 | 16560 |   133K  (1)| 00:26:41 |
|*  8 |         HASH JOIN                        |                              |  9627 |   451K|   133K  (1)| 00:26:41 |
|   9 |          VIEW                            |                              |  9627 |   366K|   133K  (1)| 00:26:41 |
|  10 |           SORT UNIQUE                    |                              |  9627 |   611K|   133K (51)| 00:26:41 |
|  11 |            UNION-ALL                     |                              |       |       |            |          |
|* 12 |             HASH JOIN                    |                              |  6639 |   421K| 66681   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|  13 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | T_CREATIVE_SELECTED_ADV_CREA | 28973 |   169K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |              NESTED LOOPS                |                              | 22243 |  1281K| 66671   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|  15 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| REPORT_FILTER_TIMERANGE      |     1 |    24 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0053942                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL          | INSERTION_TV_RADIO           | 22243 |   760K| 66670   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|* 18 |             HASH JOIN                    |                              |  2988 |   189K| 66697   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|  19 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | T_CREATIVE_SELECTED_ADV_CREA | 28973 |   169K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |              NESTED LOOPS                |                              | 10010 |   576K| 66688   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|  21 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| REPORT_FILTER_TIMERANGE      |     1 |    24 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0053942                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL          | INSERTION_TV_RADIO           | 10010 |   342K| 66687   (1)| 00:13:21 |
|  24 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL               | ASSIGNMENT_BROADCAST_GENRE   | 25135 |   220K|    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |       SORT JOIN                          |                              |   345 | 10005 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | GENRE                        |   345 | 10005 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
   8 - access("A"."BROADCAST_ID"="C"."BROADCAST_ID")
  12 - access("AD"."CREATIVE_ID"="A"."CREATIVE_ID")
  16 - access("B"."RANGE_NAME"='current')
  17 - filter("A"."BROADCAST_BEFORE_ID"<>(-1) AND "A"."INS_DATE">="B"."START_DATE" AND
              "A"."INS_DATE"<="B"."END_DATE")
  18 - access("AD"."CREATIVE_ID"="A"."CREATIVE_ID")
  22 - access("B"."RANGE_NAME"='current')
  23 - filter("A"."BROADCAST_AFTER_ID"<>(-1) AND "A"."BROADCAST_BEFORE_ID"<>(-1) AND
              "A"."BROADCAST_BEFORE_ID"<>"A"."BROADCAST_AFTER_ID" AND "A"."INS_DATE">="B"."START_ DATE" AND "A"."INS_DATE"<="B"."END_DATE")
  25 - access("TA"."GENRE_ID"="G"."GENRE_ID")
       filter("TA"."GENRE_ID"="G"."GENRE_ID")
```

What is the right way to read the difference in costs between line 6 and 7?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, shouldn't the title of this question be "How can a node in an execution plan have LARGER costs than its parent?"

Comment: @Neil: You are right, of course. I changed parent to child, so it should make sense, now.

Comment: This is expected behavior.  It's a limitation of EXPLAIN PLAN, it's not a problem.  If you need to see detailed information about the actual performance of the statement and how the optimizer is selecting the plan, trace events 10046 and 10053.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the SQL, but you probably have scalar subqueries within the overall query - EXPLAIN PLAN outputs the cost of a single execution of the subquery in this case, but doesn't know how many times it will execute.

[Edit]
I figured if I looked I would find a Jonathan Lewis reference that explains this better - see http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/10/12/scalar-subqueries/

Comment: If I understand you (and the post you linked) correctly, the optimizer assumes that a branch of the execution plan will be executed 0 times, and thus ignores the costs for that branch. Isn't this quite a dangerous assumption?

Comment: I think this is more of a case of EXPLAIN PLAN not accurately representing what the optimizer is using for a decision process - a 10053 trace is the best way to see the details of this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try another tool (TOAD / SQL*Plus / etc) to see if the result is the same (ie to determine if it's a client-display or server issue)?

Are all your tables ANALYZEd?

Comment: I tried SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and Aqua Data Studio, all of these display the same results. The tables are analyzed.